# How To Use The Paste Special Options Using Only The Keyboard (No Mouse)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel 2016 for Mac, and I'm looking for how to select the different radio buttons after I bring up the "Paste Special" window.
[image]

I can easily select the values with my mouse but I want to be able to only use the keyboard.

I'm able to press "V" to select the "Values" option, but I cannot select any other option that starts with "V" such as "Validation" or "Values and number formats"

Finally, tab does not move the cursor down to the the other sections. I cannot select "Operation", "Skip Blanks", or "Transpose"

What am I missing to select these options?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the off-chance that the Mac uses the same letters as the Windows version, here is the screenshot from the Windows dialogue. The underscored letters will select the respective option.

[image]

Comment: It does. Thanks for the response! Now I'll just have to memorize these letters. Thanks :)